# Is Heart of the Swarm sold as an expansion or a full game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I already own Wings of Liberty and am hoping that Heart of the Swarm is sold as an expansion instead of a full game.  Is there any information about this?

Comment: As outlined in our [FAQ], speculation of future releases is off-topic, which your question falls under. The reason for this is that there is no way for us to know the cost of the game outside of an official announcement from Blizzard, so answering your question is impossible Due to this I'm voting to close your question.

Comment: There is an official FAQ from Blizzard, making the question answerable.

Comment: Wipqozn should have said "answering your question **might be** impossible" - that is one of the reasons speculation on future releases is prohibited - we can only answer some of them, iff the developer has provided an answer for us to quote.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0KP4G) has Heart of the Swarm listed for $39.99 (USD).

This may just be a pre-order price for it; and subject to change after release. But you can lock into the price now if you pre-order.

[update]

If you purchased Wings of Liberty, you still need to purchase Heart of the Swarm in order to play Heart of the Swarm.

Comment: if i have Wing of Liberty . I want to update Heart of the Swarm , then can i ?. Or i must buy as individual game ?

Comment: Updated. If you want to play Heart of the Swarm you must purchase it. Wings of Liberty won't automatically upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

According to Blizzard's [FAQ](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/heart-of-the-swarm-preview/faq) for North America and Europe:

> How much will Heart of the Swarm cost?
>
> We typically don’t provide details about pricing until the game is closer to release. We do view Heart of the Swarm as an expansion set, so for the regions that have a standard box business model such as North America and Europe, we will price accordingly. For other regions that have alternative business models, we’ll provide details at a later date.

There you have it from Blizzard directly.  They consider Heart of the Swarm as an expansion.

---

To your questions in comments - in the FAQ, you must own Wings of Liberty to play Heart of the Swarm.